# cannot dropping null values using pandas

Tags: pandas, numpy

I am using the dataframe `dropna` function to drop all the null values but it is not working

```
df.dropna(how = 'all', inplace = True)
df1 = df.copy()
print(df1.isnull().sum())
```

OUTPUT:

```
Ind_ID                      0
Test_date                   0
Cough_symptoms            252
Fever                     252
Sore_throat                 1
Shortness_of_breath         1
Headache                    1
Corona                   3892
Age_60_above           127320
Sex                     19563
Known_contact          242741
dtype: int64
```

Comment: "all" in how="all" doesn't mean "drop all missings"; please see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) for what it means.

Answer (score 0):

You are removing rows which contains only `NaN`. If you want to remove rows containing at least one `NaN` you need:

```
df.dropna(how = 'any', inplace = True) #lol
```